# How do I read lines of integers from a file and parse it into a Vec<i32> in Rust?

Tags: rust, file-io

I am teaching myself Rust programming language, and I found File I/O hard to master.

I tried to rebuild a C++ project that I did before in Rust, and here is the source code:

```
 let mut file = File::open("numbers.txt").expect("Can't open file!");
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).expect("Unable to read to line.");

    let mut vec_numbers = Vec::<i32>::new();
    for line in contents.lines().into_iter(){
        vec_numbers.push(line.parse::<i32>().unwrap());
    }
```

The .txt file has the following numbers:
**53 22 87 103 -3 75 220 1 64 543 98 44**

The numbers are separated by a line each.

When I ran the code above, the compiler complains:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: Empty }', src\main.rs:11:46
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

I know how to directly read the content as a whole, but what should I do to parse the number as  and push it into a vector?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a blank line at the end that causes parsing to fail.

You can discard it like:

```rust
if !line.is_empty() { // You can also `.trim()` it if you want
    vec_numbers.push(line.parse::<i32>().unwrap());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is being caused by empty line in the file

either you can remove empty lines 
or 
filter the empty lines on the fly

```
use std::{fs::File, io::Read};

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("numbers.txt").expect("Can't open file!");
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)
        .expect("Unable to read to line.");

    let mut vec_numbers = Vec::<i32>::new();
    for line in contents.lines().into_iter().filter(|line| !line.is_empty() ) {
        vec_numbers.push(line.parse::<i32>().unwrap());
    }

    println!("{:#?}", vec_numbers);
}
```